# Is there a way to turn a class object name into the string associated with it?

Tags: python, class

So in my program, a certain function (good_function()) needs to use the string name (attribute_name) of an object when referencing an attribute(object_name.attribute) of an object(object_name). This attribute is also another object from a different class. However, when I pull out this attribute to be used, it brings up the class object name (<**main**.Class2 object at abcde12345>) instead of the name of the attribute (attribute_name). The current output and setup is as follows.

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        pass

class Class2():
    pass

attribute_name = Class2()

object_name = Class(attribute_name)
object_name.attribute = attribute_name

def good_function(thing):
    #doesn't really matter
    pass

good_function(object_name.attribute)
print(object_name.attribute)

>>> <__main__.Class2 object at abcde12345>
```

It reads "object_name.attribute"(attribute_name) "as the attribute_name"'s object ID name thingamajiggy (<**main**.Class2 object at abcde12345>) instead of just "attribute_name". So my question is: Is there a way to translate the callsign (<**main**.Class2 object at abcde12345>) into the "attribute name" to which it corresponds? (see desired output below) Thanks in advance, I hope this wasn't too confusing, and I'll be as active as I can in responses. The desired output and setup is below.

```
    cclass Class():
def __init__(self, attribute):
    pass
```

```
object_name.attribute = 'attribute_name'

def magic_function(object):
    #solve for here
    return object

def good_function(thing):
    #doesn't really matter
    pass

variable = magic_function(object_name.attribute)

good_function(variable)

print(variable)
     
    >>> attribute_name
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a runnable [mre] that demonstrates your problem. Also, are you really using Python 2.7?

Comment: You can get the class name from an instance of one using `instance.__class__.__name__` **or** `type(instance).__name__`.

Comment: @MattDMo I believe those reproduce the problem well. And yes, I meant Python 3.7, I believe I misclicked.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, that seems helpful for future use. I take it though that like KaibutsuX said, there is no way to do it. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, then I don't think what you want is possible, assuming the actual reference attribute is just a native type.

However, if you made the attribute an instance of your own custom class then any instance could implement the `__str__` method to display whatever you wanted:

```
class MyClass():
  def __str__(self):
     return 'MyClass str'
```

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and a solution, I appreciate it much!